# Karate API - How we can get the specific array element for which index will be dynamic. I need value for last array element which is not fixed

Tags: karate

I read that variable will not work as a index in array when we try to access array[i] or something like that.
so How I can or get a value for last element of the array which is dynamic. It will change after every API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables will work in JS. They won't work in JsonPath (e.g. `match` Left Hand Side), read the docs to understand the difference:

```
* def foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]
* def size = karate.sizeOf(foo)
* def last = foo[size - 1]
* match last == 4
```

Comment: Thanks. so I did it like following                                                                                                     * def size = karate.sizeOf(response.affiliates)      
 And print size      
* def nameExpected = response.affiliates[size - 1].name            
  And match  nameExpected == 'Company Affiliate1'

Comment: As you said, left hand side of the match - it's not working so I inserted one extra line to store in a variable and then compare.